# find . * -exec ll {} \; -> with just one result instead of four

Tags: find, exec, hp-ux

I'd like to use find command to search all files in one directory:

`find . * -exec ll {} \;`

Result shows four (!) results per file:

- `file123`
- `./test/file123`
- `file123`
- `test/file123`

Is it possible to show just the second result `./test/file123` using find-out-of-the-box-command (so without using things like `| grep '^\./'`)?

I'm using latest version of HP/UX.

Comment: Where do you have this command from? just use `find .` - or just - `ll`. The difference is that `find` will find files recursively. Also note. Don't use `ll` in scripts! `ll` is just an alias (In Ubuntu it means `ls -alFh`). This is not portable in any ways.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting four lines of output because you you ask `find` to search the current directory (`.`) as well as everything that `*` expands to.

For the current directory, `find` will proceed to invoke `ll` on the things that it finds, which will be the current directory, the `test` directory and the file in the `test` directory.  This lists `file123` twice.

It will then search everything that `*` expands to, which will be the `test` directory. Now it will use `ll` on `test` again and on the file within.  This lists your file twice again.

Instead, if you're looking for a regular file, use `-type f`. And you don't have to use `ll` (or `ls`) to get the results from `find` as it will list the found pathnames by default.  Also, just give `find` the current directory (or `test`) as the search path:

```
find . -type f
```

If you know that you are looking for a file with the exact name `file123`:

```
find . -type f -name 'file123'
```

If you want `ls -l`-like output rather than a pathname:

```
find . -type f -name 'file123' -ls
```

Comment: If you want to limit the results to files within those top-level directories, like "test", you might consider using the `-maxdepth` and `-mindepth` option as well. In this case: `-mindepth 2` and `-maxdepth 2`.

Comment: @ToddWalton, that's a GNU extension, now supported by a few other implementations but I doubt HPUX's is one of those. See also the better `-depth 2`  with NetBSD `find`.  See [delete folders older than 1 day](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/225842) for instance for a POSIX equivalent

Answer (score 5):

```
find . * -exec ll {} \;
```

Passes `.`, and the list of non-hidden files in the current  directory (expanded from `*` by the shell), including the `test` subdirectory (and if any of those files started with `-` or if there was a file called `!` or `(`, `)`... that would cause `find` to report a syntax error).

So you're telling `find` to look for files recursively in `.`, but also in `test`. So `find` will find `test` twice and also `test/file123` twice.

`ll` which I suppose is a script that does `ls -l` is a tool to list details of files or for files of type directory, the details of all the files in that directory (unless you pass the `-d` option).

So `ll` will be called with `./test` and `test` as arguments in which cases if will list the details of the files in its content (including `test/file`).

And it will be called with `./test/file123` and `test/file123`.

Here, you'd want:

```
find . -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(using `+` means that more than one file will be passed as arguments to `ls` which is more efficient and also lets `ls` sort that list of files).

Your `find` may even support a `-ls` predicate which behaves a bit list `ls -lsid`:

```
find . -ls
```

Comment: I never use `find .` myself because this is redundant. find will always search in the current directory if the directory is unspecified.

Comment: @Fox, that's a GNU extension. Many `find` implementations (including the original one as probably found on the OP's HPUX) require at least one file. The POSIX `find` specification does as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `find` will search recursively in all the directories. 
Find will return not only files, but also directories!

If you want to list all files within the test directory, all you need is the following command:
`find test/ -type f`

Also, I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but check your `find` manpage... You are using `-exec ll {} \;` and I suspect there's probably a `find` option that will do what you need (filter files by size, modification date, etc.)